# Django template and angularjs filtering

Tags: angularjs, django, django-templates

I have some data on the page provided by standard django queryset `{{ django_data }}` there is about 100 objects inside and I display it on the standard way

```
{% for data in django_data %}
    <div class="data_block">
        <h1>{{ data.title }}</h1>
        <div>{{ data.description }}</div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Now as angularJS novice I want to add [this filtering/search functionality](https://curran.github.io/screencasts/introToAngular/exampleViewer/#/22) to display less objects based on user input

```
Search:<input ng-model="query" type="text"/>
```

Also I think that to allow angular to make new request from the controller is wasting of resource to get data which is already on the page `http.get('django_data.json')` simply doesn't make sense. So the bast way will be to send django_data as dict from django view. If I do this, how to tell angular that data are on the page inside variable called django_data? Something like this do not work.

```
<div class="data_block" ng-repeat="data in django_data">
```